# NestJS can't resolve dependency of imported module

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I have four modules, App -> Dog -> Access -> Mongo (dependencies as shown by the arrows).
In the App also the MongoDB is connected with `MongooseModule.forRootAsync()` which is then used in the `MongoModule` with `MongooseModule.forFeature()`.
The full code can be found in this [example project](https://github.com/ChristianNavolskyi/NestJS-Modules).

I want to use the `AccessGuard` provided via the `AccessModule` (which internally uses the `MongoModule`) to be available in the `DogModule`.

With the code below I get this error message:

```
[Nest] 31164   - 11/10/2020, 5:11:29 PM   [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AccessGuard (?). Please make sure that the argument Mongo at index [0] is available in the DogModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If Mongo is a provider, is it part of the current DogModule?
- If Mongo is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within DogModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing Mongo */ ]
  })
```

app.module.ts:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async () => {
        let info = mongod.getInstanceInfo()

        if (!info) {
          await mongod.start()
        }

        info = mongod.getInstanceInfo()

        if (info) {
          return {
            uri: info.uri,
            dbName: "dogsDB",
            useCreateIndex: true,
            promiseLibrary: global.Promise,
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
          } as MongooseModuleOptions
        }
      },
    }),
    DogModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

dog.module.ts:

```
@Module({
  imports: [AccessModule],
  providers: [AccessGuard],
  controllers: [DogController],
})
export class DogModule {}
```

access.module.ts:

```
@Module({
  imports: [MongoModule],
  providers: [AccessGuard],
  exports: [AccessGuard],
})
export class AccessModule {}
```

access.guard.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class AccessGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private mongo: Mongo) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    return await this.mongo.hasDog()
  }
}
```

mongo.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: Dog.name,
        schema: DogSchema,
      },
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [Mongo],
  exports: [Mongo],
})
export class MongoModule {}
```

When I add the `MongoModule` to the `DogModule` it works.
However, that is not how it should be I guess, because the DogModule doesn't actually use the `Mongo` class.
The `DogModule` only needs the `AccessGuard` from the `AccessModule`.

Answer (score 1):

Quick note: guards and other enhancers don't need to be added to the `providers` array. They are `@Injectable()`, but they live in a pseudo-space that allows them to be outside of the `providers` arrays of `@Module()`s. Weird, I know, but it's how things are.

All the needs to happen from there is if the guard is used in a module, then that module needs to have access to the guards dependencies, in this case, the module needs to have `imports: [MongoModule]` as `MongoModule` both `provides` and `exports` the `Mongo` `@Injectable()` class

Comment: That's really weird, as I extracted the module for the `MongoModule` to get rid of those dependencies. :(